# Drag move fabric JS controls

Tags: javascript, object, canvas, fabricjs, drag

Who can help me a little with JS Fabric move / drag function?
I want the drag / move function triggered by de left top corner and I tried the code below:

```
//drag function
const dragOriginal = fabric.Object.prototype.controls.tl;
fabric.Object.prototype.controls.moveObject = new fabric.Control({
    x: -0.5,
    y: -0.5,
    actionHandler: dragOriginal,
    actionName: 'drag',
    cursorStyle:'pointer',
    render: renderIcon,
    cornerSize: 25
});
```

This gives me the following error in the console

```
actionHandler is not a function. (In 'actionHandler(e, transform, x, y)', 'actionHandler' is an instance of Object)
```

Who can help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the answer

```
fabric.Object.prototype.controls.moveObject = new fabric.Control({
    x: -0.5,
    y: -0.5,
    actionHandler: fabric.controlsUtils.dragHandler,//change to this
    actionName: 'drag',
    cursorStyle:'pointer',
    render: renderIcon,
    cornerSize: 25
});
```

I hope this is were you looking for.